# Display Childs in Parent list possible? (Parent-Child relationship list)

Tags: javascript, lookup-column, connected-web-parts

I know how to create a Parent-Child relationship between 2 lists and display the Childs in the parent form or on a Webpart near my parent list but what I would like to do is actually display the Childs **inside** the Parent list.

My parent list contains meetings. My child list contains actions.

So I wish to have:

```
meeting1
   action1
   action2
meeting2
   action3
   action4
...
```

I more than probably need to use JavaScript and wonder how to proceed. Any advice or has it already been done?

note: I don't have access to SPD